# How to compile lighttpd completely statically?

Tags: linker, static-libraries, elf, static-linking, lighttpd

I am having trouble completely compiling lighttpd statically. I have followed the directions in the  INSTALL file using autotools:

```
LIGHTTPD_STATIC=yes ./configure -C --enable-static=yes
```

I have also added "-static" to CFLAGS during compilation as well. However, when I check the elf file to see if it is completely static, I get the following output (using readelf):

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x98e10 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x408000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x479eb0
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x499e00
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x499e08
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x400308
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x404288
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x400f40
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              9392 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x49a000
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           3840 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x406cf8
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x406c50
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             168 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x406b80
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         2
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x406738
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

Specifically, I would like to statically compile libc into my lighttpd binary rather than including it dynamically. Any input would be greatly appreciated on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Different systems and different libc might not work well with static builds of 100% of the libraries.  It does not matter specifically to the lighttpd base, but it may matter to the dependencies of some lighttpd modules on other third-party libraries.

It is probably possible to adjust your environment so that autoconf prefers the all static libraries.  However, before doing that, I suggest trying to use SCons to build lighttpd statically:

https://wiki.lighttpd.net/InstallFromSource

Review the contents of `sconsbuild/build/plugin-static.h` and remove what you do not need.